# Alembic operations with multiple schemas

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, alembic

**NOTE:** This is a question I have already found the answer for, but wanted to share it so it could help other people facing the same problem.

I was trying to perform some `alembic` operations in my multi-schema postgresql database such as `.add_column` or `.alter_table` (although it will be the same question for `.create_table` or `.drop_table`). For example: `op.add_column('table_name', 'new_column_name')`

However, I was getting the same error saying basically that the table name could not be found. This, as far as I understand it, is caused because `alembic` is not recognizing the schema and is searching for that table in the public schema. Then, I tried to specify the schema in the table_name as `'schema_name.table_name'` but had no luck.

I came across similar questions [Perform alembic upgrade in multiple schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28264125/perform-alembic-upgrade-in-multiple-schemas) or [Alembic support for multiple Postgres schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109218/alembic-support-for-multiple-postgres-schemas), but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for it into the `alembic` [documentation](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#ops), I found that there is actually an schema argument for the different operations. For example:

`op.add_column('table_name', 'column_name', schema='schema_name')`

Answer (score 2):

Alembic will automatically pick up the schema from a table if it is already defined in a declarative SQLAlchemy model.

For example, with the following setup:

```py
# models.py

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name =  Column(String(50))
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "my_schema"}
```

```py
# alembic/env.py

from models import Base

target_metadata = Base.metadata

[...]
```

Running:

```sh
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "test"
```

Would result in a default migration script with a schema specified:

```py
def upgrade_my_db():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('some_table',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=50), nullable=True),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id'),
    schema='my_schema'
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```